# Connect to Ubuntu under Hyper-V in Windows 10 has mysterious x.org screen?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hyper-v

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 using Hyper-V's "Quick Create..." feature which lets me set up Linux easily and I can see the desktop but also this pesky "Connect to Ubuntun 19.04" windows as below

[image: Initial with Connect to Ubuntu]

If I click connect the following screen shows up

[image]

and if I type in my password,  it just goes "blank", like this:

[image]

Whats' wrong here?

Comment: I am experiencing same behaviour and still have no idea how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch to Basic Version.
[You can click on toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvJiD.png) or uncheck View->Enhanced session

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).